# Measure distance in real time with CoreLocation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, distance, core-location, measure

I'm making an app that measure's speed and distance in real time. so I'm having problem with measuring distance. I tried to figure out something by getting location variable outside of function by return. But if I do this, speed measurement doesn't work. So how can I start measuring distance when "start" tapped then stop when "stop" button tapped?

```
@IBAction func startStopButtonDidTouch(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if isStarted { //When tapped STOP
        timer?.invalidate()
        isStarted = false
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        startStopButton.setTitle("START", for: .normal)
   
    } else { //When tapped START
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimeLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        isStarted = true
        startStopButton.setTitle("STOP", for: .normal)
    }
}

func locationManager (_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]
    speedLabel.text = "\(Int(location.speed * 3.6))" 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting the location updates you will get updates in the `didUpdateLocations` method.

This method will work fine to start the location updates and to stop it.

```
var startLocation:CLLocation!
@IBAction func startStopButtonDidTouch(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if isStarted { //When tapped STOP
        timer?.invalidate()
        isStarted = false
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        startStopButton.setTitle("START", for: .normal)
   
  } else { //When tapped START
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    isStarted = true
    startStopButton.setTitle("STOP", for: .normal)
   }
}
```

Here you have to update your labels with distance and speed in real-time.

```
func locationManager (_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) 
{
            let location = locations[0]
            speedLabel.text = "\(Int(location.speed * 3.6))"
   if (startLocation == nil)
   {
      startLocation = location;
   }
   let endLocation = location;
            //Distance measure code will be placed here.
   //In KM
   let distance = startLocation.distance(from: endLocation) / 1000
}
```

Comment: when i will tap stop, numbers should stop updating than when i will tap start it should update from the point when i tapped stop. it shouldn't start from the zero

Comment: Updated my answer, just don't make it null on stop, it will keep the start location at it's reference.

Comment: ok Thank u for help. but how can i round distanceLabel like 2.4 or 12.8?

Comment: not relative to the question you asked but this is how you can do so `String(format: "%.1f", distance)`. Cheers!